# tsql - Can i do this in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, case, common-table-expression

I have two results sets as shown below:

@Rounding

```
PortfolioID Duration
AAA     -0.1
```

@FinalOutput

```
ReportingDate   FundCode    Sector      Rank    Duration    Weight
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector1     1       0           33.5
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector2     2       0.9         29.6
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector3     3       0.6         17.3
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector4     4       0.8         11.8
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector5     5       0.1         3.1
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector6     6       0.1         1.3
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector7     7       0           0.4
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector8     8       -0.9        0
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector9     11      0           -1.3
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector10    100     0           2.8
31/07/2013      AAA         Sector11    101     0           1.5
31/07/2013      AAA         Total       102     1.6         100
```

What i need to be able to do is subtract the Duration in @Rounding from the rank 1 and rank 102 durations, however if the rank 1 is "Sector1" then i need it to be subtracted from rank 2.  Is this possible in a case statement?  i've created the below but i can't think how to cater the case for the "Sector1" to never be subtracted upon if it is rank 1?

```
    SELECT 
        ReportingDate
    ,   FundCode
    ,   Sector
    ,   [Rank]

    ,   CASE
            WHEN [Rank] IN (1,102) THEN [Duration Contribution] - RD1.Duration
            ELSE [Duration Contribution]

        END     AS [Duration Contribution]

    ,   CASE 
            WHEN [Rank] IN (1,102) THEN Percentage - RD.[Weight]
            ELSE Percentage

        END     AS Percentage

    FROM CTE AS CTE

        INNER JOIN @RoundingDifference AS RD  -- Portfolio Weight Rounding
            ON RD.PortfolioID = CTE.FundCode

        INNER JOIN @RoundingDifferenceDur AS RD1 -- Duration Contribution Rounding
            ON RD1.PortfolioID = CTE.FundCode

    WHERE (Percentage <> 0.0
    OR [Duration Contribution] <> 0.0)

    ORDER BY    ReportingDate
            ,   FundCode
            ,   [Rank]
```

So the result i'm looking for is Sector 1 Duration to still = 0 but Sector 2 Duration and the Total to be 1.0 and 1.7 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really possible for sql to know when dealing with row N in a set whether or not it found a particular value in row N-1. This means you can't really tell it to do something special with a Rank 2 record only if the Rank 1 record had some specific Sector value.

You could, though, probably use a subquery to check if the set has a row with Rank 1 and also has Sector1.

You'd need to do this with a detailed case statement and the performance would likely be bad if the dataset is large.

```
select
    case
        when Rank = 102
            then [Duration Contribution] - RD1.Duration
        when Rank = 1 and Sector != 'Sector1'
            then [Duration Contribution] - RD1.Duration
        when Rank = 2 and exists (select * from cte where Rank = 1 and Sector = 'Sector1')
            then [Duration Contribution - RD1.Duration
        else [Duration Contribution]
    end
```